# Scala efficient set inclusion detection

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Let a collection of tuples where the first item is a set, for instance

```
val xs = Seq(
  ((1 to 5).toSet ++ Set(9), "apple"),
  ((15 to 17).toSet,         "pear"),
  ((21 to 30).toSet,         "grape"))
```

Given a value `x:Int`, how to efficiently identify the second item ? (The real use case includes thousands of sets.)

For `val x = 22` the result would be `Some("grape")`, for `val x = 19` the result would be `None`.

**Note** Values in each set are not necessarily consecutive.

**Note** Sets do not overlap (any sets intersection proves empty).

Comment: Are the values necessarily non-overlapping?

Comment: well, `xs.find(_._1.contains(x)).map(_._2)` will find first item, but if you need faster than O(N) you need some other datastructure

Comment: @SeanVieira non-overlapping :)

Comment: @dmitry thanks for the comment, a more sophisticated data structure may be worth considering...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on your use case, but given you're concerned with efficiency, I assume you're going to do a lot of lookups.

I also assume you use one `xs`, and lookup in that a lot of times.

Preprocess `xs` into a map of `Int->String`

```
val xsMap = (xs flatMap { case (s, v) => s.map((_,v))}).toMap[Int, String]
```

Then it's trivial (and O(1)) to look up elements

```
xsMap.get(22)            //> res0: Option[String] = Some(grape)
xsMap.get(19)            //> res1: Option[String] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
s.find(_._1.contains(11)).map(_._2)
```